# syncronizing across machines for a python apscheduler and wmi based windows service

Tags: python, networking, synchronization, wmi, apscheduler

I am using apscheduler and wmi to create and install new python based windows services where the service determines the type of job to be run. The services are installed across all the machines on the same network. Given this scenario I want to make sure that these services run only on one machine and not all the machines.

If a machine goes down I still want the job to be run from another machine on the same network. How would I accomplish this task?

I know I need to do some kind of synchronization across machines but not sure how to address it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to include functionality like this in APScheduler 2.0 but it didn't pan out. Maybe The biggest issue is handling concurrent accesses to jobs and making sure jobs get run even if a particular node crashes. The nodes also need to communicate somehow.

Are you sure you don't want to use Celery instead?